# Expected value of a sum of pulses

Tags: self-study, expected-value, stochastic-processes

Given a sample function X(t) of a random process as

\begin{equation}
  X(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {[\mathcal{H}(t-nT-to) - \mathcal{H}(t-nT-to-T/2)]} 
\end{equation}

where *A* and *B* are constants, and *to* is uniformly distributed from 0 to T.

The process is an ergodic one since it is an ensemble of pulse functions with a random variable as time origin (to).

How one could evaluate its expected value without arguing that it is an ergodic process (and so evaluate its time averaging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assume ergodicity etc.  $\mathcal H(t-nT - t_0)$ is a
*function* of the random variable $t_0$ and its expected value is just
$$E[\mathcal H(t-nT - t_0)] = \int_0^T \mathcal H(t-nT - x)\frac{1}{T}
\, \mathrm dx$$
and similarly for the other term.  Notice that if $\mathcal H(\cdot)$
in nonzero only when its argument is in $[0,T]$, then for any given
$t$, the integrand of the integral above is zero for all choices of $n$ except one or two specific values.  Hence, in
$$E[X(t)] = E\left[\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal H(\cdots \right]
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty E[\mathcal H(\cdots$$
most of those expectations are zero.